# CNN computer vision with Keras and open CV

Tags: python, opencv, keras, vision

I'm trying to live to detect a label in a bottle, I already have my model and weights that are working fine with images but the problem comes when I try to live to detect the label using opencv `cv2.read()` it won't detect correctly.

So what I have noticed is when I use `load_img` from Keras it work well but when I use `cv2.read()` does not work well. So is there a way to process live images with Keras instead of using `cv2.read()`?

This code below does not work well:

```
while True:
success, img = cap.read()
rect = cv2.rectangle(img, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)

cropImg = img[yMin:yMax,xMin:xMax] # this is all there is to cropping

cv2.imshow("Original", rect)
cv2.imshow("Cropped", cropImg)
x = cv2.resize(cropImg, (altura, longitud))
x = img_to_array(x)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)
val = cnn.predict(x)
#resultado = arreglo[0]
#respuesta = np.argmax(resultado)
if val == 0:
    color = (46, 242, 79)
else:
    color = (255, 0, 0)
print(val)
```

And this following code works well but is not working live:

```
while True:
success, img = cap.read()
rect = cv2.rectangle(img, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)

cropImg = img[yMin:yMax,xMin:xMax] # this is all there is to cropping

cv2.imshow("Original", rect)
cv2.imshow("Cropped", cropImg)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('t'):    
    photo = cap.read()
    #cropImg2 = photo[yMin:yMax,xMin:xMax]
    cv2.imwrite("pic.png", cropImg)
    x = load_img("pic.png", target_size = (longitud, altura))
    #x = cv2.resize(cropImg, (altura, longitud))
    x = img_to_array(x)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)
    val = cnn.predict(x)
#resultado = arreglo[0]
#respuesta = np.argmax(resultado)
    if val == 0:
        color = (46, 242, 79)
    else:
        color = (255, 0, 0)
    print(val)
```

Comment: The code in the post doesn't have a capture object being initialized. Do you have OpenCV actually using a camera?

Comment: You are expected to use `cv2.imread()`